# Create New Tab Sessions with the same working Directory

Tags: iterm, iterm2

Often in workflow you are working within a directory and then need to create a second terminal or session to the same directory.

```
TAB 1
#~/home
cd really
#~/home/really
cd long
#~/home/really/long
cd filepath
#~/home/really/long/filepath
node filepath
#session now occupied 

#new TAB
#CTR + T
#~/home
#I want to be in the same filepath
```

is there a setting somewhere to do this?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

One of the options for a profile is which directory to use when creating a session with that profile. The default is to use your home directory, but you can change that to use the previous directory instead. You can change this setting in the default profile (allowing you to continue using <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>), or you can create a new profile which uses this setting, and assign a different keyboard shortcut to create a session with that profile.

Comment: Awesome thanks! The Short Version, For Iterm2
Iterm-> Preferences-> profiles -> working directory -> Reuse Previous Session Directory

Comment: for more control: Iterm2 Iterm-> Preferences-> profiles -> Advanced Config [edit button] -> now you can choose a different action for panes or tabs or windows.

Comment: This feature is broken in iTerm2-3.3.7(The most latest one). Is there any other solution?

Comment: The "Reuse previous session's directory" option is still available in 3.3.8beta.

Comment: Fantastic! I cannot believe I didn't bother looking this up before, so useful. I'm using 3.3.9 and you can specify advanced behaviour for when you open a new tab, window or split pane.

Comment: Does it also work if I connected over `ssh`? @chepner

Comment: If for some reason iterm2 doesnt correctly detect your working directory, you can explicitly tell it, by using `echo -ne "\033]50;CurrentDir=$PWD\a"` (either as part of your `PROMPT_COMMAND` or in an overridden `cd` command)

Answer (score 36):

Preferences->Profiles->Working Directory->Reuse previous session's directory

Answer (score -8):

To open new tab with same directory we can do this.

```
shift + cmommand + D
```

Comment: tried this in Terminal and iTerm2 doesn't seem to work. @chepner gave a good solution for iterm2 users

Comment: I have use oh-my-zsh too. Have you use it ? Its no T its D

Comment: This just splits the window, with the new pane using the same profile. Whether that pane keeps the same directory depends on the profile setting.